# Extracellular potential during extracellular stimulation

Tags: electrical-signal

A biomembrane separates extracellular and intracellular space. It is known that the resting membrane potential of a nerve cell is -70mV and is caused by an electrochemical gradient acting on the inside and outside due to different ion concentrations. Potassium ions are much more concentrated inside and therefore tend to flow out of the cell (chemical force drives outward), which triggers an electrical restraining force (electrical force acts inward) - -70mV is therefore the electrical force at which equilibrium occurs.

If an electrode is placed in the extracellular space and a current pulse is sent, this creates an electric field in the extracellular space which acts on the ions (depends on whether the current is cathodic or anodic).

Now the attached photo symbolizes this extracellular stimulation and I don't know exactly why this is so:

1. when stimulating with a cathode, the positively charged particles are attracted and the negatively charged ones are pushed away -- why is there a depolarization of the cell directly under the electrode (i.e. the cell interior becomes more positive) while further away there is a hyperpolarization (the cell interior becomes more negative)?
2. with anodic stimulation it is exactly the opposite?

[image]

PS:the electric field propagates radially because the medium is isotropic and homogeneous.

Comment: Very nice question, eventhough more related with "electrochemistry", "neurochemistry" or electromagnetics by the least than DSP alone. If you are lucky, some EEG scientists can help you. In the mean time, however, please make the followings clear: electric potentials exist between two points (they are relative), hence the membrane potential being -70mV is wrt where? Second, likewise electric currents flow between sources and sinks; thus, a single probe cannot deliver currents unless there's a return path. So where is the other probe located? These may have an impact on the answer you will get.